# Visual Studio IntelliSense with Controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I am having an issue with Visual Studio 2012. The IntelliSense is ot picking up my controls in the code behind file. I'm sure if I accidentally clicked a shortcut key that messed with the settings. Is there a way to remedy and get IntelliSense to show the control id's in my aspx pages?

Comment: Try rebuilding. Intellisense will get out of sync sometimes

Comment: I did that and still the same issue, IS is only giving everything but controls(blue icons). If I open a up a different project however the IS works fine.

Comment: There may be something small wrong in the code preventing intellisense from running correctly. I had this happen when I missed a ; in another form in my session. Make sure there are no errors